# Call redirect is not working in plivo conference call

Tags: php, plivo

I have create a conference but call redirect is not working.
my code is page.

1.enter_conference.php

```
     <Response>
    <Conference callbackUrl="<?php echo $url; ?>conf_department_callback.php?conferenceid=<?php echo $currentday1; ?>&amp;Digits=<?php echo $digits; ?>"
                waitSound="<?php echo $url; ?>waitmusic.php" action="<?php echo $url; ?>call_end.php?ConferenceName=<?php echo $currentday1; ?>"
                redirect="false"  record="true" digitsMatch="0"><?php echo $currentday1; ?></Conference>
        <Response>
```

2.conf_department_callback.php

```
  $p = new RestAPI($auth_id, $auth_token);
  $params = array(
    'conference_name' => $conference, # ID of the call
 );
 $resp = $p->get_live_conference($params);
 foreach ($resp['response']['members'] as $num) {
    if ($num['direction'] == 'inbound') {
       $member_id = $num['member_id'];
       $parameters = array(
            'conference_name' => $conference, # ID of the call
            'member_id' => $member_id
        );
        $kickout = $p->kick_member($parameters);
    }
}

?>

<Response>
    <Redirect><?php  echo $url; ?>enter_conference.php?ConferenceDigitsMatch=<?php echo $ConferenceDigitsMatch;  ?></Redirect>
</Response>
```

I am also doing conference hangup and redirect to enter_conference.php page with parameter 'ConferenceDigitsMatch'. But its not working for me.

plz help me.
thank you.